# Visual SVN + CC.Net on Windows Server 2003. Can't get it work

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've been trying like crazy to get Visual SVN and Cruise Control to work and am getting nowhere fast.

The latest error I'm running into is the "invalid certificate.  not from a trusted site" since Visual SVN uses https.

Of course it's a fake SSL cert since I don't have a real one at this point.

Is there a way for me to permanently just accept the cert?  if so how?

Also, here is my ccnet.config file in case you notice something else I'm missing:

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

 <project name="Test">

  <sourcecontrol type="svn">  
   <trunkUrl>https://ws15wdet:8443/svn/Project/trunk</trunkUrl>  
   <workingDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\PROJECT\WorkingDirectory </workingDirectory>  
   <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svn.exe</executable>
   <username>user</username>  
   <password>password:)</password>  
  </sourcecontrol>  


  <triggers>  
    <intervalTrigger name="Subversion" seconds="600" />  
  </triggers>

  <tasks>
   <!-- Configure MSBuild to compile the updated files -->c:\
   <msbuild>
    <executable>C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
    <workingDirectory>C:\50MBuilds\builds</workingDirectory>
    <projectFile>Project.sln</projectFile>
    <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug</buildArgs>
    <targets></targets>
    <timeout>15</timeout>
    <logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\bin\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.dll</logger>
   </msbuild>
  </tasks>
  <!--Publishers will be done after the build has completed-->
  <publishers>
   <xmllogger>
    <logDir>C:\50MBuilds\Logs</logDir>
   </xmllogger>
  </publishers>
  <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>
 </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an svn connection with the same windows user as you are running ccnet in.
and choose the option to store the certificate. That shoul save the certificate in a place where the user can always access it. When launching ccnet, it should find the certificate.

Comment: I think I stumbled upon that on accident.  now I'm getting GAC errors, but at least it's building! :)